# Apache docker container - Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, docker, docker-compose

I use docker compose. However, when I run "docker-compose up", I came across an error : /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'.

Can you tell me where I fails ??

Project architecture :

```
project-name /
             / docker-compose.yml
             / Dockerfile
             / apache.conf
             / php.ini
             / src /
                   / index.php
                   / .htaccess
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
        - php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/30-custom.ini
        - apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
    environment:
        - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart

ADD ./src /var/www/html
```

php.ini :

```
display_errors=1
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

apache.conf (with my ip address) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

I type in the command line :

```
docker@default:/blabla/project-name$ docker-compose up
```

it returns me :

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully 
qualified domain name, using xxx.xx.x.x. Set the 'ServerName' directive 
globally to suppress this message
```

and

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', 
perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
configuration
```

and in the browser, in my ip address (http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/) :

```
500 Internal servor error
```

my .htaccess :

```
<files .htaccess>
    Require all denied
</files>
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$   /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm on windows and i use Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : I should say that if I delete rewrite rules, everything works.

Comment: Try and remove the line `RUN service apache2 restart`. You don't start an Apache when building an image.

Comment: always the same problem.

Answer (score 59):

This works for me:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:5.6-apache

MAINTAINER Raphael Mäder <me@randm.ch>

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ADD . /var/www/html
```

Don't forget to run your `docker-compose up` command with `--build` if you have already built the image previously, otherwise it will run the old image which may have not included the `RUN a2enmod rewrite` statement.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this FROM any of the httpd images? I'm more interested in an apache+mod_rewrite image as opposed to a apache+php+mod_rewrite image.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Dockerfile:

```
# Enable mod_rewrite for images with apache
RUN if command -v a2enmod >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
        a2enmod rewrite headers \
    ;fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I fixed it once I changed the order at `httpd.conf`. Specifically, I loaded the rewrite module between the server definition and the document definition.

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
Listen 80

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User daemon
    Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com
ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/m1"
    ServerName www.sub1.domain.tld
    ServerPath "/sub1/"
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^(/sub1/.*)" "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/s1$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

This allowed me to use the `httpd` container instead of the php.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
```

I wanted to share in case it helps anyone.