# .htaccess redirect "File not found" using Docker with PHP and Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, docker, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to containerize an existing web application that runs on Apache and PHP. I have it running locally on macOS's built-in Apache server and provided PHP, but I'm trying to move to Docker.

I have separate Apache and PHP containers defined in the repo root's docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        build: .docker/apache
        container_name: redactedname_apache
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
            - .:/home/wwwroot
        depends_on:
            - php

    php:
        build: .docker/php
        container_name: redactedname_php
        volumes:
            - .:/home/wwwroot
```

The existing repo is a hodgepodge of 2 Symfony versions (1 and 3) and a bunch of other stuff. It has a `.htaccess` file in its root to direct requests to the appropriate version of Symfony. Each Symfony directory also has its own `.htaccess`:

```
├── redacted-repo-name/
│   ├── .htaccess
│   ├── symfony/           # Symfony 1 repo
│   │   └── .htaccess
│   └── redactedname/      # Symfony 3 repo
│       └── .htaccess
```

Running `docker-compose up --build` builds and runs the Docker containers without a hitch. However, going to `localhost:8080` gives me the message "File not found." which I understand is a thing vhost or htaccess issue.

My vhost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Define server_name redactedname.local
    Define docrootweb /home/wwwroot
    Define logdir /var/log/apache2/

    DocumentRoot ${docrootweb}
    ServerName ${server_name}
    ServerAlias wwww.${server_name}
    ErrorLog ${logdir}/error.log
    CustomLog ${logdir}/access.log Combined

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    <Directory ${docrootweb}>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch .php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://redactedname_php:9000"
    </FilesMatch>

    Undefine server_name
    Undefine docrootweb
    Undefine logdir
</VirtualHost>
```

And the `.htaccess` in the application's root includes this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [redirect=503,last]

    # Symfony 3 Redirects
    RewriteRule ^json/platform/(.*)$ /redactedname/web/app.php/json/platform/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^json/like/(.*)$ /redactedname/web/app.php/json/like/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^json/el2/(.*)$ /redactedname/web/app.php/json/el2/$1 [QSA,L]
    #...
    # End of Symfony 3 Redirects#

    RewriteRule ^symfony - [L]
    RewriteRule ^redactedname - [L]

    RewriteRule ^index.php(.*) /symfony/web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /symfony/web/index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

The `RewriteRule ^index.php(.*) /symfony/web/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]` should handle localhost:8080/, but I see "File not found."

If I direct my browser to `localhost:8080/symfony/web/index.php` I do get served the correct page.

Perhaps of note, the `.htaccess` files in the root of Symfony 1 and Symfony 3 look like this:

symfony/.htaccess (Symfony 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /symfony/web/$1 [L]
```

redactedname/.htaccess (Symfony 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redactedname/web/$1 [L]
```

Thank you for any help! I'm trying to push Docker/containers at my organization and getting this working is a prerequisite, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064289/1816774? Probably you need to have `RUN a2enmod rewrite` in your Dockerfile

Comment: @Tim I have this in my apache Dockerfile: `RUN a2enmod proxy_fcgi ssl rewrite proxy proxy_balancer proxy_http` so I don't believe that's the issue

Comment: @amacrobert, I think, you may follow this link: https://docs.boltcms.io/5.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works

It will help to check whether the `.htaccess` file is working or not as well as the `mod_rewrite` module.