# SEO URL gives 404 error in OpenCart 2.3 with Docker

Tags: docker, .htaccess, url, docker-compose, opencart

Im trying enable seo_url in Opencart 2.3 on lockalhost(with Docker), but url's give me 404 error.
.htaccess renamed, cache clear.

How it works on docker ?

THANKS !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firs of all - take default **.htaccess.txt** file form your versions OpenCart pakage. If you made some changes in your .htaccess - it is better to take the original one. In other case - skip this step.
2. You have to rename **.htaccess.txt** into **.htaccess**. It's not so obvious on Windows. Open it with notepad and then **Save As** the file, renaming it to **.htaccess** without `.txt`. Hope, you done this already, but for everyone else who will read this - make sure you have done it.
3. If your are using inner folder for your OpenCart site, and the address is like *http://localhost/inner_folder/* - your rewrite base in .htaccess should be **RewriteBase /inner_folder/**. If the OC folder is domain root - rewrite base is **RewriteBase /**
4. Although, make sure that you are using **Apache** web server with **modrewrite**. Go to php error log - maybe you will find there some info.
5. Make sure the **Use SEO URLs** is **Yes** in *System> Settings > your store > Server*.
6. There is SEO URL field in **every** category, product, manufacturer. You should fill SEO URL field of each of them to SEO URL works correct. In SEO URL you should use only Latin symbols, digits, minus(-) and underscore (_). No spaces or other special characters.

**UPDATED**

If apache doesn't see .htaccess file - you should go to apache .conf file (/httpd/httpd.conf for Docker) and add after VirtualHost block

```
<Directory /var/www/html/your_folder/>
    Options Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Directory - is a path from Docker root. Restart apache. Should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Directory without inner folders. All requirements done. But still not work..

Comment: If it will help you to solve a problem - you can mark it as accepted. Any additional questions you can ask here, in comments. Will try to help you as I can.

Comment: Lets check if rewrite_mode is enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063573/apache-docker-container-invalid-command-rewriteengine/38064289

Comment: And test, if htaccess works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewriterule-not-working

Comment: I checked everything. I gues, Apache doesn't seem to find htaccess at all

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: Yes, I did the same and it works!

I uploaded the file from the container to the local host and edited it

docker cp <container-name>:/etc/apache2/ .

then upload my apache.conf to container and restart it
docker cp apache2.conf <container-name>:/etc/apache2/

Thanks for Help !