# Puppet Docker PHP Apache setup - Invalid command 'RewriteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined

Tags: php, docker, apache, puppet

I am using puppet docker (https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/docker)
and setup PHP-Apache website using PHP docker image (https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2.34-apache/images/sha256-77e5a326252f951aa557f48829973f67e8efde9c52f81ee4e4a5473a59a217d9?context=explore)

The PHP script works fine but when I added .htaccess file in folder, it is throwing error

```
[Mon Jan 25 09:52:12.078604 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.2.34 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 25 09:52:12.078766 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jan 25 09:52:32.734378 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 16] [client 172.17.0.1:50756] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
172.17.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:09:52:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
172.17.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:09:52:32 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 489 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
[Mon Jan 25 09:56:33.265445 2021] [autoindex:error] [pid 18] [client 172.17.0.1:50830] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
172.17.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2021:09:56:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 493 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
[Mon Jan 25 09:56:52.186711 2021] [core:alert] [pid 17] [client 172.17.0.1:50854] /var/www/html/packageContent/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I believe I need to `RUN a2enmod rewrite` as in here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064289/376702)

I don't know how can I set up using puppet docker(https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/docker).

Can anyone please guide me? Here is my puppet code.

```
 docker::image { 'docker.io/php':
    image_tag => '7.2.34-apache'
  }

  docker::run { 'test123.com':
    image            => 'docker.io/php:7.2.34-apache',
    command          => 'apache2-foreground',
    expose           => ['80'],
    ports            => ['8101:80'],
    volumes          => ['/var/www/test123.com:/var/www/html'],
    hostname         => 'test123.com',
    restart_service  => true,
    before_stop      => 'echo "So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish"',
    before_start     => 'echo "Run this on the host before starting the Docker container"',
    after_stop       => 'echo "container has stopped"',
    after_start      => 'echo "container has started"',
    extra_parameters => [ '--restart=always' ],
  }
```

I am running docker in Linux RedHat

Ref:
[.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m)

Comment: If you need to `RUN a2enmod rewrite` in the `Dockerfile`, then that would likely be most achieveable in a multi-stage build, and you can manage the resulting image from the new `Dockerfile` in Puppet. Modifying the `Dockerfile` of an image from the official repository is likely not possible in Puppet (or otherwise) without extensive additional coding.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuild PHP apache official image with the following configuration

```
# Dockerfile

FROM docker.io/php:7.2.34-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

puppet code changes in pp puppet class

```
      docker::image { 'php-apache7234':
        docker_file => '/tmp/Dockerfile',
        subscribe   => File['/tmp/Dockerfile'],
      }
    
      file { '/tmp/Dockerfile':
        ensure => file,
        source => 'puppet:///modules/mydocker/php_apache/Dockerfile',
      }

  docker::run { 'test123.com':
    image            => 'php-apache7234',
    command          => 'apache2-foreground',
    expose           => ['80'],
    ports            => ['8101:80'],
    volumes          => ['/var/www/test123.com:/var/www/html'],
    hostname         => 'test123.com',
    restart_service  => true,
    before_stop      => 'echo "So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish"',
    before_start     => 'echo "Run this on the host before starting the Docker container"',
    after_stop       => 'echo "container has stopped"',
    after_start      => 'echo "container has started"',
    extra_parameters => [ '--restart=always' ],
  }
```